# Handlebars NodeJS/Koa Script/Src Reference

Tags: css, node.js, reference, handlebars.js, koa

The answer is probably going to make me bang my head on the keyboard, but for the life of me I can't seem to figure out how to reference a template file so that I can load it from a handlebars view.

Let's say the view is 'ROOT/views/intro/home.html'. In it I want to reference an external CSS file called style.css.

Let's say that this external CSS file is located at 'ROOT/assets/css/style.css'.

How would I reference this file in the view in the `<link ref=""></link>` tag? I have tried everything from

'**../../assets/css/style.css**' to

'**../assets/css/style.css**' to

even appending localhost to the front and referencing

'**localhost/assets/css/style.css**'.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! For anyone else having this problem, you have to declare the static path for public files in the middleware, using something like koa-static and opening up that folder for access like:

```
_app.use(serve(__dirname + '/public/'));
```

Hope this saves someone a lot of time! It definitely was a trip trying to figure this one out.